# How to modify version of apt installed package?

Tags: apt, dpkg, versions

for example, by use `apt install xxx` I installed some deb package on my ubuntu xenial system.

```
grub2-common                       2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14
```

How do I modify this version so that `dpkg -s xxx`( or just any command output from dpkg utility) will return my customized version number?

here would be an example of modification result from output of `dpkg -l | grep grub2-common`

```
grub2-common                       2.02~unicorn<3-9ubuntu1.999
```

Comment: Do you mean changing the version number without actual reinstalling? Why do you need this?!

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep xxx` will show details of installed package, `apt-cache policy xxx` too - is that what you mean/need ?

Comment: @Melebius the use case is pretty niche here, I want to stop specific package to be automatically updated by some sysadmin scripts.

Comment: @cmak.fr and how is that going to help me modify the version?

Comment: what you exactly want to do?

Comment: @cmak.fr to MODIFY the package version, I think I made that clear in the post itself.

Comment: In this case, [holding the package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package) should be preferred.

Comment: @Melebius I do want to achieve "Modification" of package version,  any other means such as holding the package is not ideal for my case. perhaps I should investigate more on dpkg database itself.

Comment: @Sajuuk no clear to me, cant help

Comment: I’m afraid you are trying to solve an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please add details about your “sysadmin scripts”. Perhaps they are not designed well and should be fixed instead of breaking the package system even more…

Comment: @Melebius the problem I have is actually more complex and should not be take into the picture here, I'm very certain what I want exactly is the capability to modify package version, rather than just stop my package from getting updated in my oversimplified example.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to discover that by modify `status` file under `/var/lib/dpkg` directory (requires root permission), one would be able to get modified package version which  reflect in dpkg utility output.